# Google Earth elevation profile and the missing values

Tags: kml, google-earth, elevation, missing-data

I have some nice data from research aircrafts that I put into kml-files like the example below. If you check the elevation profile, you find the
extended Data plotted nicely.

My problem: my data contains missing values. If I try an empty  in place of the missing data, the extended data doesn't appear
more in the profile frame (you can delete one of the floats in the gx-value pair to see).

My question to you: Is there any hack to make GoogleEarth draw the profile without the missing values (i.e. interrupted)?
Or do you know a way to give the GE developers a feedback?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:xal="urn:oasis:names:tc:ciq:xsdschema:xAL:2.0">
    <Document id="feat_1">
        <Style id="stylesel_0">
            <LineStyle>
                <color>ff0000ff</color>
                <colorMode>normal</colorMode>
                <width>4</width>
            </LineStyle>
        </Style>
        <visibility>1</visibility>
        <Schema id="schema_1" name="Flight Track">
            <gx:SimpleArrayField name="bb" type="int">
                <displayName>Flight Track</displayName>
            </gx:SimpleArrayField>
        </Schema>
        <Placemark id="feat_2">
            <name>example</name>
            <styleUrl>#stylesel_0</styleUrl>
            <gx:Track>
                <gx:coord>-140.0 10.0 0.0</gx:coord>
                <gx:coord>-133.572123903 7.66044443119 4131.75911167</gx:coord>
                <gx:coord>-130.15192247 1.73648177667 9698.46310393</gx:coord>
                <gx:coord>-131.339745962 -5.0 7500.0</gx:coord>
                <gx:coord>-136.579798567 -9.39692620786 1169.77778441</gx:coord>
                <gx:coord>-143.420201433 -9.39692620786 1169.77778441</gx:coord>
                <gx:coord>-148.660254038 -5.0 7500.0</gx:coord>
                <gx:coord>-149.84807753 1.73648177667 9698.46310393</gx:coord>
                <gx:coord>-146.427876097 7.66044443119 4131.75911167</gx:coord>
                <gx:coord>-140.0 10.0 5.99864288729e-28</gx:coord>
                <altitudeMode>absolute</altitudeMode>
                <ExtendedData>
                    <SchemaData schemaUrl="#schema_1">
                        <gx:SimpleArrayData name="ext">
                            <gx:value>0.00217237382056</gx:value>
                            <gx:value>0.107224360838</gx:value>
                            <gx:value>1.99669920652</gx:value>
                            <gx:value>14.0278818114</gx:value>
                            <gx:value>37.1819210687</gx:value>
                            <gx:value>37.1819210687</gx:value>
                            <gx:value>14.0278818114</gx:value>
                            <gx:value>1.99669920652</gx:value>
                            <gx:value>0.107224360838</gx:value>
                            <gx:value>0.00217237382056</gx:value>
                        </gx:SimpleArrayData>
                    </SchemaData>
                </ExtendedData>
            </gx:Track>
        </Placemark>
    </Document>
</kml>
```

Answer (score 0):

This does look like a bug.

I have created an issue at http://code.google.com/p/earth-issues/issues/detail?id=1399

If you star it then you will be notified of any updates.

Meanwhile you may wish to preprocess your KML data and place interpolated values where you have missing ExtendedData.